# Cannot get dynamic highlightings with Vespa

Tags: vespa

I'm looking for a small example to produce a dynamic summary from a string field.

The content:

```
{"wpsolr_title": "Hamster one"}
```

The schema:

```
field wpsolr_title type string {
  indexing: index | summary
  summary: dynamic
}

fieldset default {
  fields: wpsolr_title
}
```

The query:

```
{"query":"hamster","yql":"select wpsolr_title from wpsolr30 where (userInput(@query))"}
```

The results:

```
{ "fields": { "wpsolr_title": "Hamster one"} }
```

Answer (score 0):

The query and configuration described below will return

```
{ "fields": { "wpsolr_title": "<hi>Hamster</hi> one" } }
```

That is, the matching term will be bolded with the default markup. It will not generate a dynamic snippet since the field value is too short.

Comment: I cannot get the bolding. Is there another configuration required?

Comment: No other configuration needed. I just tried with your config and query and that works fine. Maybe try with a minimal configuration?

Comment: After many tests, it appears that adding a condition prevents the bolding. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that adding a where condition to the userInput prevents the summary in results.

userInput() alone:

```
vespa query \
  'yql=select wpsolr_title from wpsolr30 where (userInput(@query))' \
  'query=hamster'

 "fields": {
                "wpsolr_title": "<hi>Hamster</hi> one"
            }
```

userInput() with another condition:

```
vespa query \
  'yql=select wpsolr_title from wpsolr30 where (userInput(@query)) and true' \
  'query=hamster'

 "fields": {
                "wpsolr_title": "Hamster one"
            }
```

Comment: New Vespa issue https://github.com/vespa-engine/vespa/issues/26693

Comment: Yes, but only when the additional condition is *true* rather than an actual condition.